# django listing by category , with indexview and detailview classes

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using generic views for list and details, on the index page I am getting my list but not getting my category list, but I am getting a category list on another template.
I want to list the category on the index page, and on click of that category, image go to that list which is filter by that specific category.
I hope you understand my question 
. below is the view for brand index and model for category

```py
class BrandsIndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "brands/index.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_brands_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brands.objects.filter(created_on__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_on')[:10]

model for category 

class Category(models.Model):

    category_name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=200)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    category_image = models.FileField(upload_to="brand_cat_images",null=True,blank=True,validators=[file_ext])

class Brands(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=False,help_text="Enter Brand Name")
    brand_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200 , unique=True)
    brand_logo = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="brand_logo")
    brand_description = models.TextField(max_length=250 ,null=True,blank=True)
    brand_category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE ,default="None",related_name="category")
```

Comment: Provide the code you are rtying like models and views for us to understand.

Comment: check the question again i added the code

Comment: where is your brands model ?

Comment: added in the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a brands listview which is filtered by category slug, then define a url which accepts the category slug as argument.
You could use the get_queryset method as below:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    cat_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
    cat = Category.objects.get(category_slug=cat_slug)
    qs = cat.brands_set.order_by('brand_name')
    return qs
```

Example url:

```
    path('categories/<slug>', views.BrandsListView.as_view(), name='brand_category'),
```

Template example:

```
      <a href="{% url 'brand_category' 'some_category' %}">
```